# How to execute test runner with multiple tags in Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I want to execute two specified test cases one by one
I have test runner configured like below

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
    glue = "classpath:",
    plugin = { "html:src/test/resources/execution/report/cucumber-reports.html" },
    tags = "@Test213 and @Test214"
)
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestRunner {
}
```

but when I run it none scenarios is executed - only @Before from testNG.

Console output:

```
14:32:09.036 [main] INFO  integration.RestFXTestBaseClass - New browser instance opened
14:32:09.039 [main] INFO  cleaner.RestFXCleaner - Cleaning execution directory...
14:32:09.044 [main] INFO  cleaner.RestFXCleaner - Items deleted

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: In the future, it won't hurt if you include the versions you are running (i.e. Cucumber version, TestNG version, even Java version. Sometimes the answers could vary depend on the software versions you are running.

Comment: Cucumber 6.9.1, TestNG 7.0 and Java 11

Answer (score 2):

It was due to my wrong understanding of this tags handling.
I thought that I need to join scenarios for execution by `and` but it's logical `and`
so this `tags = "@Test213 and @Test214"`executes only scenarios which are annotated by both these tags and there are not any in my suite.
If I want to run scenarios one by one I need to configure it like this `tags = "@Test213 or @Test214"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is caused by `glue = "classpath:"`

In Cucumber, the "*glue*" is the location (folder) for your step definitions. I am sure your step definitions folder is not named `classpath:`. If the folder where your step definitions reside is called *tests* and it is inside your project, you could use a relative path such as `glue = "tests"`. Most people choose to name their step definitions folder as *stepDefinitions*.

Also, make sure your *tags* are correct or you may see a similar problem.

***UPDATE***: According to the info provided by M.P. Korstanje, the `glue` can be a classpath URI. However, your URI is empty. The problem is the same: You are not letting Cucumber know where to find your step definitions. You need to provide either a package (i.e. *com.myapp.mypackage*), a path (i.e. *com/myapp/mypackage*), or an URI (i.e. *classpath: http://com/myapp/mypackage*).

Comment: Cucumber supports both package names, classpath uris and windows paths. I'd not recommend using the latter two but it's still valid. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/feature/GluePath.java#L19

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Didn't know that. Thanks! For the OP, the classpath was empty. The issue remains the same, right? The problem is the value of the `glue` tag. (or lack thereof)

Comment: No. See the other answer. But give it a try to convince yourself.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I think you missed the part where I stated this "_Also, make sure your tags are correct or you may see a similar problem._" I know about the "and" and "or" issue with Cucumber. I have seen that plenty. You can check out the edit history. The comment was there from the beginning.... just in case YOU need to convince yourself. :D

Comment: The glue path, wether correct or incorrect will not affect the discovery of scenarios. As such mentioning it is not relevant to the OPs question. Additionally the OPs glue path is correct. So telling the OP to change it will not help them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'or' if you want to run scenarios that are annotated with either of these tags.

'And' is to run scenarios that are annotated with both the tags

Sometimes we would want to run some regression scenarios that are failed in the last run.

So, that time we can use 'and' -> @Regression and @Defect